nftables bridge filter all traffic on a specific bridge master
Using the nftables bridge table is there a way to filter all forwarded traffic through a particular bridge? Let's say I have br0 with members eth0 and eth1 is there a way to write a table like
table bridge filter {
  chain forward {
    type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
    iif "br0" accept
  }
}

Basically I don't want to filter on the bridge members, I want to have a rule that filters everything on br0
